# What is the derivative of $\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ using the first principle?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I find the derivative of $$\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$ using the first principle.

Please help me, how to go step by step. Thanks

Comment: Which first principle?

Comment: rewriting to $x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}$ might already do the trick for you

Comment: @Glorfindel **THE** first principle... :-)

Answer (score 8):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

$$f^{\prime}(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$

$$= \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h} + \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{h} $$

$$= \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}} - \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h\sqrt{x+h}\sqrt{x}} $$

$$= \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}\sqrt{x}\big(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}\big)} $$

$$= \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \dfrac{1}{2x\sqrt{x}}$$

$$= \dfrac{x-1}{2x\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

I'am doing the computation at $x=1$.

From $$\sqrt t-\sqrt1+\frac1{\sqrt t}-\frac1{\sqrt1}=\frac{t-1}{\sqrt t+\sqrt1}+\frac{1-t}{\sqrt1\sqrt t(\sqrt1+\sqrt t)},$$

We deduce

$$\lim_{t\to1}\frac{f(t)-f(1)}{t-1}=\frac1{\sqrt1+\sqrt1}-\frac1{\sqrt1\sqrt1(\sqrt1+\sqrt1)}.$$

Up to you to generalize for other $x$.